# popscene in cocos2d problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

i am new to cocos2d.In my game am using "cctouchesbegan" to push a new scene.Using "popScene" am coming to my first scene from  second scene.After coming to first scene my "cctouchesbegan" delegate method not working... If any idea,it will be helpful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put "NO" when you are adding the targettedDelegate as shown below.It corrects my error [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO]

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];


    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
}


- (void) onExit {

    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];
    [super onExit];
}
```